# Incorrect syntax near AS - SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I can't create this stored procedure, the error tells me that the syntax of AS is incorrect. Please help! I have searched everywhere where my error could be or how I can redefine the stored procedure, and I have not had success.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PRC_BizAgi_Obtener_Anualidad]')
             AND type in (N'P'))
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_BizAgi_Obtener_Anualidad]
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_BizAgi_Obtener_Anualidad]
    @id_NinoCentro INT 
AS
    DECLARE @periodo INT
    SET @periodo = YEAR(GETDATE())

    /*SET @id_NinoCentro = ncp.id_Nino;*/

AS <-------- INCORRECT SYNTAX
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ncp.id_NinoCentro,
        CAST (MAX(ncp.Ano) AS VARCHAR)+''+ 
              CASE 
                 WHEN MAX(ncp.Mes) > 9 
                    THEN CAST(MAX(ncp.Mes) AS VARCHAR) 
                    ELSE '0'+ CAST(MAX(ncp.Mes) AS VARCHAR)
              END AS periodo
    FROM
        nino_centro_pago ncp 
    WHERE
        periodo = @periodo
        AND ncp.id_NinoCentro = @id_NinoCentro
        AND ProductoFlex = '101'
        AND PagaInscr = 1
    GROUP BY
        ncp.id_NinoCentro
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 6
END
```

Comment: I dont think this should be tagged as C#, it has nothing to do with C#

Comment: You have two `AS`

Comment: I was about to say the same thing,I should work on my typing speed

Answer (score 2):

Right after the parameters, you should have `AS ... BEGIN ...` and that's all - right now, you have the `AS` twice - right after the parameters, and again after declaring and setting the `@periodo` variable - you should have **one `AS` only**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_BizAgi_Obtener_Anualidad]
    @id_NinoCentro INT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @periodo INT
    SET @periodo = YEAR(GETDATE())

    -- rest of your procedure here....

END
```